# Is there a Facebook changelog?

Tags: facebook

Facebook makes major interface changes fairly frequently. I'm not adverse to change, but I'd like to know what's changing and why. Is there an public, up-to-date Facebook changelog?

Answer (score 1):

You can find them in their blog - https://developers.facebook.com/blog . As usual they post list of issues\changes that were released

And also there is a roadmap for future changes, that can be found here - https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Comment: I found that, but as far as I can tell it's an API changelog, not a changelog of user-facing features. Am I missing something?

Comment: Seems yes, you are right. It's mostly related to API changes. There is a blog at https://blog.facebook.com/, but it has just major updates.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no official public facing documentation of user interface changes to Facebook, even when those are quite significant (ex: May 2016 changes to behavior of Facebook Groups and Group Suggestions).

I have not been able to find a good 3rd party resource for change publication either.